What does a pointer to an array represent?
I found out that arrays are actually similar to pointers and the variable they are contained in gives 1 element of the array when unpacking. So does a pointer that points to that array, and my question is why if we increment the pointer by one (using an increment) we will get the next element in the array?  Are all the array elements next to each other in memory?

Arrays are not pointers, they are different. But they can decay into pointers e.g. when passed to a function.

Also, a pointer to the array itself, and a pointer to an element of an array, are two completely different things, even if they point to the same memory address (ie, when pointing at the 1st element).

the easiest way to prove to yourself that an array is not the same as a pointer is to do static_assert(sizeof(int[10]) == sizeof(int*))  That will fail which means that they can't be the same thing since they are different sizes.

"Are all the array elements next to each other in memory?" Yes.

I recommend you take out a pen and some paper. On the paper draw two boxes, label one pointer and the other array[0]. Now draw an arrow from pointer to array[0]. That's how pointers work, really, by pointing to something else in memory. In the case of arrays, they decay to a pointer to the first element of the array (i.e. array[0]).

Note in current C++ array/pointer decay is not such a big thing anymore as it was in the past. C++ has std::array , std::vector (owning arrays) and std::span (a view on a (sub)part of an array. I would say learn to about those first (and maybe revisit the pointer issue later).  std::array for exmple allows you to let functions return arrays (without making memory managment problems for the calling code).

int* p{}; int a[1]{}; int v{}; Given those, p = a; will have the pointer point to a[0], via decay.  Or p = &v; will have the pointer point to v.  A pointer is a fundamental type that holds a value, and that value is an address.  That value may be nullptr, or may be a valid address (or other states: stale, dangling, wild, uninitialized).  A pointer may point to an array, or may point to a single object — the pointer doesn't distinguish between the two.

A pointer to a single object, e.g. int, does not guarantee that incrementing the pointer will point to another object of the same type.


Recently I found out that arrays are actually similar to pointers

This statement is wrong.  Arrays are not pointers, period.  However, in certain contexts, such as variable/parameter assignment, an array can decay into a pointer to its 1st element.

So does a pointer that points to that array

A pointer to the array itself, and a pointer to an element of an array, are two completely different things, even if they happen to point at the same memory address (ie, when pointing at the 1st element).

why if we increment the pointer by one (using an increment) we will get the next element in the array.

That is just simple pointer arithmetic.  When you increment a typed pointer, the memory address it holds is incremented by the byte size of the type of the pointer.  So, for example:
T arr[2];
T* ptr_1 = arr;       // ie &arr[0]
T* ptr_2 = ptr_1 + 1; // ie reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ptr_1) + sizeof(*ptr_1))

ptr_1 points at the 1st element in arr[0], and ptr_2 points at the 2nd element in arr[1], because ptr_1 is of type T* so the address in ptr_2 is sizeof(T) bytes higher than the address in ptr_1:
arr
+-------+-------+
|   0   |   1   |
+-------+-------+
^       ^
ptr_1   ptr_2

Now, take the same concept and apply it to a pointer to the array itself, rather than a pointer to an element:
using ArrayOfT2 = T[2];
ArrayOfT2 arr;
ArrayOfT2 *ptr_1 = &arr;
ArrayOfT2 *ptr_2 = ptr_1 + 1; // ie reinterpret_cast<Array2*>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(ptr_1) + sizeof(*ptr_1))

ptr_1 points at arr itself, and ptr_2 points at the address after arr, because ptr_1 is of type ArrayOfT2* so the address in ptr_2 is sizeof(ArrayOfT2) bytes higher than the address in ptr_1:
arr
+-------+-------+
|   0   |   1   |
+-------+-------+
^               ^
ptr_1           ptr_2


Are all the array elements next to each other in memory?

Yes.  An array is always stored as a single contiguous block in memory.

The simple answer is: yes. Array elements are stored together in the memory (which is why we cannot change their length). Syntax pointer[n] means the same as *(pointer+n), but it's easier to read. Although arrays aren't pointers (they keep data such as array size), arrays are passed to functions as pointer, which can cause quite a bit of a headache if you aren't aware of it

The biggest headache is that there's no way for a function to know the size of the array that was passed to it, unless the size is also passed as a parameter.

@MarkRansom unless the array parameter is a reference/pointer to the actual array itself, rather than a (decayed) pointer to one of its elements. In which case, the size of the array WILL be known in the referenced/pointed type.

@RemyLebeau true, but it's not at all obvious how to achieve that so you don't see it very often.  And you can play games with templates too to get the array size at compile time.

@MarkRansom It's really not that hard to do, it is just not something is that commonly done nowadays with the existence of std::vector and std::array. And a template is needed only if you want to pass fixed arrays of different sizes to the same function.
